# Can We give the Code Pool Outside the "code" Directory in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Can We give the Code Pool Outside the "code" Directory in Magento like

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
define('BP', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

Mage::register('original_include_path', get_include_path());

//echo get_include_path(); 

//die('This is included path');

if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    $appPath = COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH;
    set_include_path($appPath . PS . Mage::registry('original_include_path'));
    include_once COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . "Mage_Core_functions.php";
    include_once COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . "Varien_Autoload.php";
} else {
    /**
     * Set include path
     */

    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'custom' . DS . 'custom'; 

   /* 'custom' is My own folder name present out side the code directory */

    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local'; 
    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'community';
    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';

    $appPath = implode(PS, $paths);
    set_include_path($appPath . PS . Mage::registry('original_include_path'));
    include_once "Mage/Core/functions.php";
    include_once "Varien/Autoload.php";
}
```

it is Not working for me. is there any method to put the codepool out side the "Code" Directory in magento.

Comment: I have to ask, why are you trying to create a custom code pool?  What purpose would it benefit?  The 3 code-pools already cover the essentials, and adding a custom one would be over-complicating things.  It would also require you to hack up each version of Magento if you choose to upgrade, and also confuse developers who are familiar with the standardized code pools.  You're writing extensions specific to yourself?  Use the local code pool, that's what it's for.

Comment: Dear Axel, i am asking you why magento gives the path for code pool like  $paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local'; instead of  $paths[] = BP . DS .'code' . DS . 'local';   it means you can create your own code pool any where in the 'app' directory and that is not working in my case. i know the 3 code pools covers the All Essential parts even we don't need to create a custom codepool also. but why the magento gives the path for codepools like that.  is there any way to create a code pool outside the code directory, just i want a code pool outside the "Code" Directory @Axel

Comment: You're modifiying a core file, Magento's isn't giving you anything.  You've merely found where Magento defines it's codepools.  I'm just letting you know that creating your own is not a recommended approach and will most likely be the cause of issues down the road for you.  It's over-complicating things and goes against Magento's code standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your custom codepool by putting below line in your `app/Mage.php`

```
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'custom';
```

that I expect that you already know.

But if you want to keep your codepool in app/custom then creating symlink for your codepool will be the easiest way. Infect you can place your codepool anywhere in your system.

This is how you will create your symlink(considering `/home/deependra/public_html` is your magento root directory)

```
ln -s /home/deependra/public_html/app/custom/custom/ /home/deependra/public_html/app/code/custom
```